# Numpy.where workaround

Tags: python, numpy

For my arrays:
`array([[  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],  #a`
       `[ 1,  3,  5,  7,  9],`
       `[ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25],`
       `[ 2,  4,  6,  8,  5]])`

and
`array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4, 16],  #b`
       `[ 1,  3, 16,  7,  9],`
       `[ 5, 16, 15, 20, 25],`
       `[ 2,  4,  6,  8,  5]])`

I try to get the result of `np.where((a==5 and b==16))`. I expect:

`Out[1]: (array([0, 1], dtype=int64), array([4, 2], dtype=int64)`,

since that's where `5` and `16` share the same indices; but instead i get a

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

When i try `np.where((a.all()==5 and b.any()==16))`, i get

`Out[1]:  (array([], dtype=int64),)`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `&` instead of `and`:

```
np.where((a==5) & (b==16))
```

When dealing with numpy arrays you want to use the bitwise operator instead of the logical and.

Comment: The more pedantic answer is np.where(np.logical_and(a==5, b==5))